# How to update resource file in TFS in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I write an application in VS2013. The source code of app is managed by TFS. My application contains a resource file, that contains some images. When I add a new image to resource file, everything working correct after updating resource file to server. But when I replace some existing image in resource file with another image with the same name, nothing is updated. On the server remain original old image. 
Do you have some tips how to update resource file after changing only image content? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I just marked changed images in Resources folder solution by "Check Out for Edit.." TFS option and then I updated it by "Check-in" TFS option. Now its all fine